# PHP file that accepts file path from loop and returns an image

Tags: php

I am trying to display multiple images from my database through a loop. Basically it's something like this

```
while loop is running{
$_SESSION['path'] = $imageURL;
echo '<img src="pic.php">';
}
```

my idea is the pic php gets the path then displays it. Then another path comes in and it returns the image again.

HOWEVER IT DID NOT. It just returns the last image retrieved and repeat it until the loop is done.

so instead of displaying a.png, b.png and c.png. What displayed were 3 c.png.

here is my pic.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['path'];
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

fpassthru($fp);
exit;
?>
```

I'm particularly new to this stuff so it will be a great help if you guys check this out! TYIA!

Comment: A script like this is very dangerous - by passing the proper `path` parameter value, this could be used to read _any_ file on your webspace, so for example one storing database credentials. This needs at least further checks on the file ending/type, or something limiting it to within a certain base path (such as a dedicated /images/ directory.) Do not _use_ this in this form on any publicly reachable website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what happens:

1. You access your web page through your favorite browser
2. The server process your request, and asks PHP to create an HTML file containing 3 `<img src="pic.php" />`
3. The server returns the HTML file to your browser
4. The browser analyze your HTML file and detect it has links to external resources, indeed it has 3 times `pic.php`, so it begins to ask the server to return the content of this file
5. The server process again the request and asks PHP to return to him the content of `pic.php`
6. The server returns this content, and **HTML put it 3 times**

You can see at the end, even if you looped 3 times and changed 3 times `$_SESSION['path']`, the server comes *after the war* and only see `c.php`, so it returns it to the browser.

You should adopt another strategy to fetch your images.

**Workaround**

One way to fix the issue is to fetch image "at demand" like this:

*pic.php*

```
<?php
session_start();

$name = filter_var($_GET['q'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

fpassthru($fp);
exit;
?>
```

*index.php* (the file you access)

```
<?php
while loop is running{
    echo "<img src='pic.php?q=$imageURL'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow! I totally get it! Been wondering for a while why it did not work but now I get it! Got to find another way now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @astrophine I added a suggestion of issue fix if it helps.